# Best method to upgrade atoti version?

Tags: python, olap, jupyter-lab, olap-cube, atoti

I was trying to import atoti to my jupyterlab as

```
import atoti as tt
```

I encountered the below problem.

---

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-385abead9553> in <module>
----> 1 import atoti as tt

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\atoti\__init__.py in <module>
     29 __edition__ = str(_EDITION)
     30 
---> 31 check_license(_EDITION, _LICENSE_END_DATE)
     32 
     33 __all__ = [

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\atoti\_licensing.py in check_license(edition, end_date)
    144     for output in get_license_outputs(edition, end_date):
    145         if output.output_type == OutputType.EXCEPTION:
--> 146             raise Exception(output.content)
    147         if output.output_type == OutputType.REGULAR:
    148             print(output.content)

Exception: To keep using atoti, update to atoti's latest version or upgrade to Atoti+.
```

Can I simply use Conda or pip to upgrade the atoti version or there are some precautions I need to keep in mind so as to not disrupt my environment?

Comment: If you are using a virtual environment (venv) then you may use Conda or pip freely. If you're not, there's a small risk that you might break something else.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I am a developer at atoti*

This happens because atoti community edition comes with a license that is only valid 64 days. There will always be a new version or a new build with a valid license and you should move to it.

### Conda

Conda is smart enough to use the latest build or version so you can simply run

```sh
conda update atoti
```

### Pip

If there is a new atoti version you can upgrade to the latest like any other package

```sh
pip install --upgrade atoti
```

If there is no new version and only a new build you have to uninstall and re-install atoti:

```
pip uninstall atoti
pip install atoti
```

Note that your build version is visible in the package name. For instance for [atoti 0.4.3 on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/atoti/#files) there is build 0 released on Sep 1, 2020 and build 1 released on Oct 21, 2020 which is still valid.

Comment: The idea of the every 64 days expiring license only adds to walking away from atoti

Answer (score 2):

With the 0.5 release, it will be better to upgrade the atoti-jupyterlab and other atoti associate plugins as well.

`conda update atoti atoti-jupyterlab`

Refer to https://github.com/atoti/atoti/issues/209

Comment: One may need to un-install the previous version first (Conda or Pip)